# How to manually add a library to a visual studio 2017 project?

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio, static-libraries, dynamic-library

My apologies for this very basic question that has assuredly been asked and answered before, also for my very dated terminology. I searched for an answer, but failed to find anything helpful. I am using the latest update of VS 2017 Community, and I'm trying to manually add what I used to call a "function library" to a project, which sits under a "solution".

The project is simply a C++ or C# console application. What I have is a .h (header) file, a .lib (static library) file, and a .dll (dynamic library) file. I intend to make "function calls" to this library. I'm aware that I need to have my dll in the debug folder where the executable resides, but I'm not sure how to "add dependencies" in VS 2017. I know how to manage and install NuGet packages, but these files aren't a handy-dandy NuGet package.

I hope to get advice on doing this the right (VS 2017) way.

Comment: have a look at [How to add references in VS2017](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkze6zky.aspx), it might help.

Comment: @vikscool, thanks for that link. Definitely worth a read, but it doesn't refer specifically to the old static libraries and header files. But I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 8):

What I do in a situation like this is to create a folder, I use `C:\Etc\SDKs\<name_of_library>` and then within that folder create an `include` subfolder, and a `lib` subfolder.  Note that the top level folder choice is completely arbitrary, place it where it makes the most sense to you.

In the `C/C++` section of project properties on the `General` tab, or the corresponding section for C# projects, there's an entry for `Additional include directories`.  Add the path to your newly created `include` folder there.  That'll let you include the header file and have it work right.

In the `Linker` section of project properties, also on its `General` tab, there's a corresponding entry for `Additional library directories`.  Add the path to your `lib` folder there.  On the next tab down: `Input` there's an entry for `Additional Dependencies`.  Add the actual name of the library file there.

Those steps should allow your project to be built using the `.h`, `.lib` and `.dll` files you have.

-- Edit to address comments --

The `.lib` file does go in the `...\lib` folder, and the `.h` file in the `...\include`, that's correct.  However, you had the location of the `.dll` correct in your original question.  That needs to be somewhere on the search path that the executable will find, so the easiest place is the same folder as the executable.

`General` tab is a poor choice of words on my part.  `General` section might have been better here.  When looking at the project properties, the left most pane is a tree view of the various property sections.  With everything closed up, except the very top item open, you'll see

```
Configuration Properties
    General
    Debugging
    VC Directories
  > C/C++
  > Linker
    ...
```

If you then double click on `C/C++` it'll open up, and show the sections specific to the C/C++ compiler:

```
Configuration Properties
    General
    Debugging
    VC Directories
  V C/C++
      General     <<<<<
      Optimization
      Preprocessor
      ...
  > Linker
    ...
```

If you click on the word `General that I've highlighted, that'll get you to the General section / tab I was talking about.

Likewise, double clicking the word `Linker` will open up that section, and under that you'll find the Linker `General` and `Input` sections.

Let me know if this still isn't clear, and I'll try to clarify.

Comment: Ok, thanks for this advice. I'll give it a whirl and report back here.

Comment: So, do I put the .lib file in the \library subfolder? And the .h and .dll files go in the \include folder? Obviously I missed something. Maybe it doesn't matter.

Comment: Ok, I gave up on the C# project. I created a C++ console app, and was able to add the .h file to the project under "Header Files". Never did find a "General" tab anywhere, and therefore was not able to find an entry for "additional library directories". Sigh. Thanks for the suggestions though.

Comment: Alright.. this is great clarification. Now I've got more gas in the tank. I'll give this a whirl and report back.

Comment: Ok, I did everything as you described, including putting a copy of my .dll file in the \lib folder because I was getting the error
 `LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'ModelRisk_Core.dll'`
because I think the linker was looking for the dll. However, after doing that, I got the error message
`ModelRisk_Core.dll : fatal error LNK1107: invalid or corrupt file: cannot read at 0x2C8`
So, now I'm thinking you gave me good instructions, but my dll is bad.

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to include the `.dll` file as part of the link stage, i.e. as one of the `Additional Dependencies` on the `Input` subsection of the `Linker` section.  You probably don't want to do that, you should be including the `.lib` file there.  Once the `.lib` is successfully linked in, the operating system will take care of loading the `.dll` when you actually run the program.  Best way to remember this: `.lib` needed to build, `.dll` needed to run.

Comment: _In the Linker section of project properties, also on its General tab, there's a corresponding entry for  Additional library directories._
This section doesn't exist in VS 2017 15.9.14. I've been just trying to link a .lib file for the past few days, why is this so difficult? It's ridiculous.

Comment: @user2445507 It appears to be fixed in VS2019 16.2. Opening `Project Propertise`/ `Linker` / `General`, the first three entries are `Output File`, `Additional Dependencies` and `Additional Library Directories`.