# Visual Studio - Create exe inclusive of ssh.dll

Tags: c++, visual-studio, compilation

I have built a simple program in Visual Studio, as per the below.

```
#define LIBSSH_STATIC 1
#include <libssh/libssh.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello World!\n";
    
    ssh_session my_ssh_session;
    int verbosity = SSH_LOG_PROTOCOL;
    int port = 22;

    my_ssh_session = ssh_new();
    if (my_ssh_session == NULL)
        exit(-1);

    ssh_options_set(my_ssh_session, SSH_OPTIONS_HOST, "10.10.10.100");
    ssh_options_set(my_ssh_session, SSH_OPTIONS_LOG_VERBOSITY, &verbosity);
    ssh_options_set(my_ssh_session, SSH_OPTIONS_PORT, &port);

    ssh_free(my_ssh_session);
   
}
```

For the Lisssh library, I have downloaded the code from here:
https://github.com/ShiftMediaProject/libssh/releases

...and added the library to Visual Studio, following the instructions here
[How to manually add a library to a visual studio 2017 project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52250894/how-to-manually-add-a-library-to-a-visual-studio-2017-project)

The library works and the program compiles, my only issue is that in order for it to work I have to manually copy a file called ssh.dll into the folder where the program executes from.

I have tried in Visual Studio setting C/C++, Code Generation -> Multi-threaded (/MT) to statically link the library, but the DLL is not getting included.

How can I create a single executable, that includes the ssh.dll?

Thanks

Comment: You can also add the directory to the environment path.

Comment: Would that not mean all clients the file was run on would need access to the file at that path? My objective is to have a single exe that can run on a PC with no external file dependencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `.dll` is a *Dynamic* Link Library; it's not meant to be included in an `.exe`. There are ways, but they are ugly and difficult.

The "proper" and easier way is to build libssh as a *static* library instead; this will give you a `.lib` file that you can add to your `.exe` easily.

It looks like [the downloads you used](https://github.com/ShiftMediaProject/libssh/releases) already contain these `.lib` files. Just add the `libssh.lib` file to your project, and omit the `ssh.lib` (which is just an import library for the `.dll`, as you can tell from the size of the file).

Comment: Thanks, makes sense. Unfortunately, when I link to libssh.lib. I get 100+ LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp_strdup ConsoleApplication1 C:\Users\admin\source\repos\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\libssh.lib(base64.obj) type messages

Comment: Compiling as x86 fixed the above errors. Marked as answered. Thanks